# как сделать изменение класса при скролле в Angular cli 5

Tags: angular5, angular-cli

нужно задать исчезновение блока при скролле страницы.
Работает при нажатии кнопки, но не скролле.

файл .ts

```
  isActive = 'false';
  t = 0;

@HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
 pageScrolled(isActive){
 let a = this.t += 1;
 isActive = 'true';
 console.log('scrolled', a, isActive);
}
```

html

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 500;top: 0; padding: 20px;
background: yellow;" class="app-header"
     [class.active]="!isActive"
     [class.hide]="isActive">

  Example

</div>
```

Comment: А что не работает при скролле? Событие onscroll вызывается? Также, возможно, нужно переменно `isActive` присваивать булевоское значение, а не строчку. А именно `isActive = true`

Comment: Спасибо! Я немного по другому переписал все и заработало. `isActive: boolean = false; ` `this.isActive = true;`

Comment: Я про это и говорил в своем комментарии))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае неправильно был задан параметр isActive

сменив в объявлении

```
isActive = 'false';
```

на

```
isActive: boolean = false;
```

и отслеживании действия

```
isActive = 'true';
```

на

```
this.isActive = true;
```

все удалось исправить